# Show multiple rows in single report row to reduce number of pagination

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

It is possible to do something like this in SSRS or T-SQL ?

[image]

The idea is that report will be printed and user will have option to fill some of the columns manually. Because there are only few columns, plenty of space on the paper remains unused. It is possible to add multiple rows into one report row ?

Comment: ONe idea: you could set up 2 tablixes in your report, and filter the one of the left to display odd row numbers, and the one on the right to display even ones (so 1 and 3 would be on the left, and 2 and 4 on the right).

Comment: Check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078346/10755978) for how to implement the idea that @Larnu mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ID column is identity and you are going to show all the rows then in T-SQL you may write such query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
          SELECT AVG(ID) AS avgValue
          FROM   t
      ) 
 SELECT t1.ID,t1.col2,t2.ID,t2.col2
 FROM   t                   AS t1
        CROSS JOIN cte
        LEFT JOIN t  AS t2
             ON  t2.ID = cte.avgValue + t1.ID
 WHERE  t1.ID <= cte.avgValue
 ORDER BY t1.ID, t2.ID
```

If ID is not IDENTITY or not all rows are selected then before selecting you will have to add a ROW_NUMBER column for all needed rows and use it instead of ID for joining.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, which support's multiple column sets is following

```
select * from (
    select top 10 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber <= 10 
) t1

left join (
    select top 10 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber > 10 and rownumber <= 20 
) t2 on t1.subsetRowNumber = t2.subsetRowNumber

left join (
    select top 10 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber > 20 and rownumber <= 30 
) t3 on t1.subsetRowNumber = t3.subsetRowNumber
```

[image]

It depends on use of `ROW_NUMBER()` function and left join. The `@products` is table variable which also contains `ROW_NUMBER()` column (it contains result of original query which we want to split).

Update: I add dynamic rows split for real use of the script

```
declare @totalRows int = (select count(*) from @products)
declare @rows int = ceiling(cast(@totalRows as decimal) / 3)

select * from (
    select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber <= @rows 
) t1

left join (
    select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber > @rows and rownumber <= @rows * 2 
) t2 on t1.subsetRowNumber = t2.subsetRowNumber

left join (
    select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name ASC) AS SubsetRowNumber,
    p.RowNumber,
    p.Number from @products p
    where rowNumber > @rows * 2 and rownumber <= @rows * 3 
) t3 on t1.subsetRowNumber = t3.subsetRowNumber
```